# Storage settings on iOS crashes while calculating

Tags: ios, crash, storage

If I navigate to Settings > iPhone Storage and wait while storage usage is calculated (Text under the categories bar says "Calculating category sizes..." and the location where individual apps appear shows just the spinner) Settings crashes without completing the calculation, leaving me unable to manage the storage on my iPhone.

How do I manage storage on iOS (without resetting completely)?

Comment: Settings app sometimes crash when calculating storage if the device has a lot of content. Did you try clearing the RAM? To clear the RAM, hold down power button till slide to power comes up then hold the Home button till Home screen appears. The phone's RAM will be cleaned out.

Comment: @NimeshNeema: iPhone X: no Home button.

Comment: Enable Assistive touch from Settings → General → Accessibility → Assistive Touch. Got to Settings → General → Shut Down. Tap on the soft-touch Home button, then hold the Home button for 2 seconds until you see the ‘Slide to Power Off’ screen disappear. That's it, the RAM is cleared. You can turn off the AssistiveTouch button. Source: http://www.nafisa.co.za/how-to-clear-the-ram-on-iphone-x/

Comment: @NimeshNeema: That doesn't help, but it's interesting to know how to reset RAM on an X!

Answer (score 2):

Most of the iOS crashes like this are corruption from data and not reproducable. If you power down the device while it’s in airplane mode - no data connection and power up, try again.

If you can reproduce this crash, you can be sure it’s the data on the device that you can control at that point. Check a backup and/or delete any and all apps and data you don’t need. At some point, you’ll need to restore the os on the device or manage storage via USB / cable / iTunes.

Comment: My rule at this point is that the next thing that requires a restore to get basic functionality working will be my signal to dump Apple and use something else. I need an platform I can use for work, not just for Facebook and Snapchat.

Comment: For reference, how do I "manage storage via USB / cable / iTunes"? I don't see a way to manage app storage there.

Comment: Well, good luck with Android on that front. At least iOS has recovery methodology, documented & reproducible.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I was thinking maybe paper and pencil (at this point I honestly think it would be more efficient)!

Comment: i've tried it - some days my monitor surround looks like 'Bruce Almighty' on a bad day ;))

Comment: Would backing up using iTunes, resetting, and then restoring from that backup fix the issue, or would the issue get restored too?